# LOCATE function produces error "OAR-01861: literal does not match format string"

Tags: oracle, ora-01861

Very new to Oracle.

I'm using some code from a friend but it's producing the above mentioned error.

```
select count(REFERENCE_#)
from ARADMIN.ALL_REQUESTS
where (DATE_OCCURRED >= add_months(sysdate, -12) )
and ({FN LOCATE('INFO-MGMT-SRVCS.R3', "ALL_REQUESTS"."TRACE_LOG")} > 0)
```

I google around and most of the hits were related to dates, so my newbie assumption is that Oracle is trying to convert the string literal `'INFO-MGMT-SRVCS.R3'` to a date.

Is this correct?

If so how do I tell it that this is in fact a string and should remain as is?

If I'm incorrect why am I getting this error?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I just tried

```
select count(REFERENCE_#)
from ARADMIN.ALL_REQUESTS
where (DATE_OCCURRED >= add_months(sysdate, -12) )
and ({FN LOCATE('foo', "ALL_REQUESTS"."TRACE_LOG")} > 0)
```

and it gave me the same error so my assumption was wrong.

**Edit 2:**
This appears to be related to my first where clause `(DATE_OCCURRED >= add_months(sysdate, -12) )`. I thought it had to do with my second one because of the line number the error message was reporting.

**Final Edit:**

Working code:

```
select count(REFERENCE_#)
from ARADMIN.ALL_REQUESTS
where (to_date(DATE_OCCURRED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= add_months(sysdate, -12) )
and ({FN LOCATE('INFO-MGMT-SRVCS.R3', "ALL_REQUESTS"."TRACE_LOG")} > 0)
```

**Moral of the story**

Don't believe the line number the error message says.

Comment: to_date is assuming your default format, you should specify one specifically.  Your working code has to_date, but you don't have it in the non-working code.  Try to_date(date_occurred, 'MM/DD/YYYY') or whatever format that string is in.

Comment: I'll edit my working code because I had to put in a date format. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to_date with a format on your non-working code?